# Python: Convertion of seconds from an initial date to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have measurements taken from 1st January 1993. They were recorded in second elapsed from that date. I would like to have them in date time.

I know in MatLab the function would be

`time = datenum(1993,01,01,00,00, time)`

However, I struggle to find an equivalent function in Python.

I have tried:

`datetime.fromordinal(time)`   doesn't work because 'module object has no attribute fromordinal'?

`datetime.datetime(time)` doesn't work (I have a matrix because there are many scans done)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Can you provide a minimal but complete example of your python code, including your import of `datetime` and your definition of `time`?

Comment: In your MATLAB example, is `time` seconds? I am looking at the use case `DateNumber = datenum(Y,M,D,H,MN,S)` on the MATLAB docs.

Comment: Side note, if you do `import datetime` then `fromordinal()` will only work with `datetime.datetime.fromordinal()`. This is because the `datetime` _module_ has multiple objects inside it, such as `datetime.datetime`, `datetime.time`, `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(your timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

You will first have to create a datetime object for Jan 1st 1993 and then add the number of seconds to that date. The code below should help you get started.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

original_date = datetime.strptime('01-01-1993', '%d-%m-%Y')
original_date + timedelta(seconds= 10000)
```

output: datetime.datetime(1993, 1, 1, 2, 46, 40)

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have list of timevalues in seconds starting from 1993-01-01 00:00.

Easiest would be:

```
datevec=[datetime.datetime(1993,1,1,0)+datetime.timedelta(seconds=val) for val in timevector]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is like UNIX time, but with a different start.

You can compute the offset once:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt.datetime(1993,1,1).timestamp()
725842800.0
```

and use it in your program:

```
OFFSET = 725842800.0
mydate = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(OFFSET + seconds_from_1993)
```